# Expected area of a circle given pdf of radius

Tags: probability

The measured radius of a circle, R, has probability density function

\begin{equation}
f(r) =
\begin{cases}
6r(1-r)  \;\;\;\; \textit{if  0 < r < 1}\\
0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;otherwise
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

what is its expected area?

I know that for continuous pdf

\begin{equation}
E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\;f(x)\;dx
\end{equation}

Comment: Hint: you are finding the expectation of r squared multipled by pi.

Comment: @thedilated Do mean I solve for $A(R) = \pi \int_{0}^{1} r [6r(1-r)]^2\;dr$ ?

Comment: The square should be on the r instead not 6r(1-r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected area is
$$A = E(\pi R^2) = \pi \int_0^1 r^2 6r(1-r) \,\text d r.$$